# How do i change a list element's value in a for loop in python?

Tags: python, list, element

I am having a bit of trouble changing the values of list elements when utilizing a for loop. The following code outputs 10 and 5 - but I'm expecting 10 and 10.

```
amount = 5
costFieldList = [amount]

for index, field in enumerate(costFieldList):
    if type(field) is int:
        costFieldList[index] = field*2
        print(costFieldList[index])
print(amount)
```

Is this an issue of scope? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're printing the list *element*, not the list itself. You have replaced the element, but the old one is still in scope, and that's what you're printing. Try `print(costFieldList)` instead.

Comment: *Is this an issue of scope* sort of. You print amount which is still 5. You change the value of 5 that is in the list, but that is not what you print at the end

Comment: Basically, I want amount to now have twice its original value so that print(amount) outputs 10. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: dont use `type(field) is int` use `isinstance(field, int)`

Comment: It doesn't make sense to also update amount inside the loop. You don't need a loop if you have only one value. You can change the value before creating the list. Or if you have multiple values in the list, then you should know how you want to update amount. Most people cannot read minds.

Comment: you never updated amount --> and I variable wouldn't change .. check  id(amount) and  id(field) if it's the same.. I think there might be confusion in mutability of the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set both `amount` and  `costFieldList[index]` to `field * 2` use:

```
amount = 5
costFieldList = [amount]

for index, field in enumerate(costFieldList):
    if isinstance(field,int):  # use issinstance to check if field is an integer
        costFieldList[index] = field * 2
        print(costFieldList)
        amount=costFieldList[index] # set amount to value of costFieldList index 
print(amount,costFieldList ) 
(10, [10])
```

Answer (score 1):

You are printing `amount` at the end.  This is set to an immutable value (5).

If your last line is `print(costFieldList)`, you will see that it is `[10]` as expected.  You used amount to initialize the list, but there is no link back to modify amount.

Answer (score 1):

By writing `costFieldList[index] = field*2`, you are creating an entirely new int instance which then overwrites the "reference" to the instance in the array, but not the value itself. So you lose the reference to the original value of `amount`.

At this stage `amount` still has a "reference" to `5` which is why you get 5 as the second output.